# final String vs final Integer

Tags: java

my java class

```
private static final String constantString = "Constant";    
private static final Integer constantInteger = 5;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s2 = constantString + "append"; // LINENUMBER 9
    Integer i2 = constantInteger + 7; // LINENUMBER 10
}
```

Byte code

```
 LINENUMBER 9 L0
    LDC "Constantappend"
    ASTORE 1
   L1
    LINENUMBER 10 L1
    GETSTATIC TestClass.constantInteger : Ljava/lang/Integer;
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/Integer.intValue()I
    BIPUSH 7
    IADD
```

**Question No1 : Why compiler not replacing final Integer (constantInteger) value with 5,but for String it did!**

if remove final keyword for Integer variable

java code :

```
private static Integer constantInteger = 5;
```

byte code :

```
LINENUMBER 10 L1
GETSTATIC TestClass.constantInteger : Ljava/lang/Integer;
INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/Integer.intValue()I
BIPUSH 7
```

**the byte code is same in two different cases (static final Integer , static Integer)**

**Question No 2 : Then What is the use of making Integer final ?**

Comment: "Then what is the use of making Integer final ?" The compiler won't let you change the value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler does not bother to notice that a final Integer with a non-null value is, necessarily, non-null. So it goes ahead and unboxes it. It is entirely possible that the JIT compiler will improve this on the way to machine code; it seems pretty unlikely either way that this is a real problem for the performance of your application.

'final' is about semantics, not performance. The language guarantees the semantics; the performance is entirely at the whim of implementors. So, to answer 'question #2' explicitly: the point of final is to have the semantics of preventing modification. Also note the rules for embedded anonymous classes, where they may only use final local variables.

Answer (score 6):

Speculation: reason is string interning. The compiler interns strings and has optimization for concatenation of interned strings. But it does not intern Numbers, and apparently lacks the optimization.

I can't think of any reason why it couldn't optimize the Integer case, other than it just hasn't been implemented in compiler. As mentioned in other answers, Integer + involves boxing / unboxing operations, quite different from string + and its implicit StringBuilder optimizations and interning logic. So String + optimization probably comes "for free" from compiler implementation point if view.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer: try `static final int constantInteger = 5`

The compiler can only replace constant expressions. Java has so-called primitive values, the types that start with a lower case character (long, int, char, ...). These values are not objects, thus they cannot have a state and can be replaced directly.

As an **optimization** String *objects* can also be treated like constants by the compiler. At runtime, a String is just a container that holds a character array, but at compile time, the compiler pretends that the String is just character data. However, `String` is the only class for which this exception was made.

For a similar reason, you can use `String` and `Class`, but no other object type for values in annotations.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Java Language Specification, v3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/jls3.pdf):

> Strings computed by constant expressions (§15.28) are computed at
>   compile time and then treated as if they were literals.

Your string expression, being composed of two literals, gets computed at compile time into a single literal. Integers get no such treatment.