# Strange Java behaviour with static and final qualifiers

Tags: java, final

In our team we found some strange behaviour where we used both `static` and `final` qualifiers. This is our test class:

```
public class Test {

    public static final Test me = new Test();
    public static final Integer I = 4;
    public static final String S = "abc";

    public Test() {
        System.out.println(I);
        System.out.println(S);
    }

    public static Test getInstance() { return me; }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test.getInstance();
    }
}
```

When we run the `main` method, we get a result of:

```
null
abc
```

I would understand if it wrote `null` values both times, since the code of static class members is executed from top to bottom.

Can anyone explain why this behaviour is happening?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446088/java-in-what-order-are-static-final-fields-initialized (and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423376/java-initialization-order-issue-static-vs-instance-fields)

Comment: You can look at the answers for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431388/final-string-vs-final-integer) .
hope it helps.

Comment: Heh. Another confusion attributable to Java's privileged types.

Comment: Marked as duplicate now… is that the _newsletter effect_?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

These are the steps taken when you run your program:

1. Before `main` can be run, the `Test` class must be initialized by running static initializers in order of appearance.
2. To initialize the `me` field, start executing `new Test()`.
3. Print the value of `I`. Since the field type is `Integer`, what seems like a compile-time constant `4` becomes a computed value (`Integer.valueOf(4)`). The initializer of this field has not yet run, printing the initial value `null`.
4. Print the value of `S`. Since it is initialized with a compile-time constant, this value is baked into the referencing site, printing `abc`.
5. `new Test()` completes, now the initializer for `I` executes.

Lesson: if you rely on eagerly initialized static singletons, place the singleton declaration as the last static field declaration, or resort to a static initializer block that occurs after all other static declarations. That will make the class appear fully initialized to the singleton's construction code.

Answer (score 71):

`S` is a compile-time constant, following the rules of [JLS 15.28](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28). So any occurrence of `S` in the code is replaced with the value which is known at compile-time.

If you change the type of `I` to `int`, you'll see the same for that, too.

Answer (score 22):

You have strange behavior due to the `Integer` data type. Regarding [JLS 12.4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2) static fields are initialized in the order you write it, BUT compile-time constants are initialized first.

If you do not use the wrapper type `Integer` but the `int` type, you get the behavior you want.

Answer (score 14):

Your `Test` compiles into:

```
public class Test {

    public static final Test me;
    public static final Integer I;
    public static final String S = "abc";

    static {
        me = new Test();
        I = Integer.valueOf(4);
    }

    public Test() {
        System.out.println(I);
        System.out.println("abc");
    }

    public static Test getInstance() { return me; }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test.getInstance();
    }
}
```

As you can see, the constructor for `Test` gets called before `I` is initialized. This is why it prints `"null"` for `I`. If you were to swap the declaration order for `me` and `I`, you would get the expected result because `I` would be initialized before the constructor is invoked. You can also change the type for `I` from `Integer` to `int`.

Because `4` needs to get autoboxed (i.e., wrapped in an `Integer` object), it is not a compile-time constant and is part of the static initializer block. However, if the type were `int`, the number `4` would be a compile-time constant, so it would not need to be explicitly initialized. Because `"abc"` is a compile-time constant, the value of `S` is printed as expected.

If you would replace,

```
public static final String S = "abc";
```

with,

```
public static final String S = new String("abc");
```

Then you would notice the output of `S` is `"null"` as well. Why does that happen? For the same reason why `I` also outputs `"null"`. Fields like these that have literal, constant values (that **do not** need autoboxing, like `String`) are attributed with the `"ConstantValue"` attribute when compiled, which means that their value can be resolved simply by looking into the class' constant pool, without needing to run any code.

Comment: Sure about that? I would expect `System.out.println("abc");`, instead of `System.out.println(S);`, since the Compiler inlines compile time constants.

Comment: You're right. In the former case there would be an `ldc` instruction rather than a `getstatic`. That's what I was trying to get at with the last sentence, I suppose I should clarify it.

Comment: And your code should show that, since you said OPs gets compiled into that.

Comment: @Tom That is a distinction without a difference. `S` is another name for `"abc"`.

Comment: @EJP Maybe not here, since declaration and access are both in the same class, but it is important to differ both if they are in different classes.